# How to extract certain variables from env?

Tags: bash

I have several variables in env that I want to extract to file kaniko.env

Env consists of numerous variables:

```
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_VTNR=7
...
```

The variables I **want to export**

```
X3_KNK_IMAGE_LATEST="false"
X3_KNK_GIT_TAG_IMAGE_TAG="true"
X3_KNK_SHORT_SHA_IMAGE_TAG="true"
```

The variables I **don't want to export**

```
X3_KNK_BUILD_ARG_BASE="BASE=Python"
X3_KNK_BUILD_ARG_VER="VER=3.6"
X3_KNK_BUILD_ARG_*...
```

I tried to use it and it works

```
env | grep -E "X3_KNK_(?:(?!BUILD_ARG).)*" >> kaniko.env
```

But it does not work for grep inside container because of grep version

```
bash-5.0# grep -v                                                                                                                                                                                                
BusyBox v1.31.1 (2020-06-02 02:36:36 UTC) multi-call binary.
```

displaying error

```
egrep: bad regex 'X3_KNK_(?:(?!BUILD_ARG).)*': Invalid preceding regular expression
```

So, How can I extract variables?

Comment: `env | grep "X3_KNK_"  | grep -v "BUILD_ARG" > kaniko.env` maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following looks ok:

```
vars=($(printf "%s\n" "${!X3_KNK_@}" | grep -v "BUILD_ARG"))
if ((${#vars[@]})); then
   export "${vars[@]}"
fi
```

`${!X3_KNK_@}` is a bash extension that expands to all variables named with that prefix.

> X3_KNK_(?:(?!BUILD_ARG).)*': Invalid preceding regula

`(?:...)` is a lookaround not supported in extended regular expressions. For that, use perl regex `grep -P`.